# Image not showing on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, xcode9.3

I have created an iOS APP for iPad and my application is using XIB.
On XIB I have put a `UIImageView` and `UIButtonview` and set the image on both of them.
The image is showing on XIB but when I am testing it on simulator then both of these views is not showing.
I have checked hidden and alpha of both views.

I have debugged my source code and found that it may be because of Alpha. You can see the attached screenshot. I have not written any source code in my .m file, simply load the viewcontroller from xib But still it's Alfa is changing I don't how alfa is changing
[image]

In my project ,I am also using following source code

```
/***** MyView.h************/

@interface UIImageView (MyView)

- (void) setAlpha:(float)alpha ;

@end

/***** MyView.M************/

@implementation UIImageView (MyView)

- (void) setAlpha:(float)alpha 

 //here alpha value is always zero but under xib it's value is 1
 //I Don't know why here I am getting zero

{

    [super setAlpha:alpha];

}

@end
```

I don't know why it is happening, can anyone please help me.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from the simulator?

Comment: have you tried setting the proper constraints to imageView?

Comment: @hitesh put some code or screenshot so we can get the idea what is happening.

Comment: I have debugged my source code and found that it may be because of Alpha.You can see attached screen shot.I have not written any source code in my .m file,simlpy load the viewcontroller from xib
But still it's Alfa is changing I don't how alfa is changing.

Comment: Why you are adding category to UIImageView? You already have alpha method, I would suggest remove this category and if you want to change alpha just use setAlpha method.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution my self I need to use "CGFloat" at the place of "float"

```
/***** MyView.h************/

@interface UIImageView (MyView)

- (void) setAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha ;

@end

/***** MyView.M************/

@implementation UIImageView (MyView)

- (void) setAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha 
{

    [super setAlpha:alpha];

}

@end
```